# How to align input buttons vertically. Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code I'm using to try to render a group of button elements vertically.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="width: 80%;background-color: grey;">
  <div class="btn">
      <label class="btn btn-warning">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
      <label class="btn btn-warning">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
      <label class="btn btn-warning">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trouble is the buttons are rendered side-by-side, instead. Am using bootstrap3.

The only way I have managed to get them to render vertically, is by including radio styles, which I want to avoid. And I want to use input fields so I can dynamically set/reset checked values. I will be using dom-selectors to alter the state of the radio group elements.

Can anyone offer some idea as to how to do this?

Comment: Use the .btn-group-vertical class to create a vertical button group

Comment: Yes, thanks. This did the trick, as initially suggested by jeroenpeters.

Comment: Great to hear! Could you please mark the answer as accepted to 'close' the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups you should change your first line from

`<div class="btn-group" ...`

to

`<div class="btn-group-vertical" ...`

Answer (score 0):

put the buttons inside a div block they will get vertically align

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="width: 80%;background-color: grey;">
    <div>
        <div class="btn">
            <label class="btn btn-warning">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 2
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="btn">
            <label class="btn btn-warning">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
                </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="btn">
            <label class="btn btn-warning">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```